# tub overfowed, didn't realize floor and pad are wet. pulled up thought was dry. when i cover with pad and carpet gets wet

Tags: water, concrete

I have been drying with space heater and dehumidifier,. however if i put carpet back it gets saturated. I am drying for several days, then cover with carpet, after 5 days carpet is dripping wet again.It is a corner about 3x4. I covered with foil and tape it wasn't wet just with pad and carpet. Stays dry if not covered

Comment: You need to edit your question so that we can comprehend what you saying. There are many missing words and much missing information.

Comment: See what i did there, i pointed out they were leaving out words and i **left out a word**.  "what you *are* saying"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Username makes it sounds like they cfeated an account solely to ask this question.  DV and VTC for being totally incomprehensible **and then ghosting**- well it is the holiday, I'll hold off for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you dry up all the water, and then the water comes back, then you have a leak somewhere. It was probably just a coincidence that the tub overflowed and the leak made itself known at the same time. You need to find the leak.